# directx 9 draw font on texture

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

What im currently doing is drawing multiple textures on a single IDirect3DTexture9 and then scale it to make a nice animation using ID3DXSprite.

Im searching a way to draw text on that final IDirect3DTexture9, however ID3DXFont does not apparently support it.
TextOut requires the DC of the texture and in consequence requires the texture to be in format D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, which will make me lose my opacity support.

Is there anyway to do this without coding my own font engine?

DirectX9 and C++

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using legacy Direct3D9 exactly? Otherwise I'd suggest using [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and ``SpriteFont``.

Comment: Sadly in this current world... people are still using XP and we cant really do something about it but supporting it.

Comment: Depends on your target market of course. The [Valve Steam Hardware Survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey) shows less than 2% of users on Windows XP. The two places you are likely to still find Windows XP in use today are: (a) emerging markets like South Korea, China, and Russia which all basically have systems frozen in amber ~15 years ago, and (b) slow-to-upgrade enterprises settings that have locked down their network to the point that they aren't likely to be running your application. These days, Windows 7 is the 'legacy' gamer system you need to worry about and it supports DX11.

Comment: Thats the thing, the reason valve has less than 2% is probably because the players doesnt have a good enough hardware to play on steam games. My customers are all from thailand and my main income is from cyber cafe, and trust me, the money is huge over there, only becasue of the easy of payment in thailand, lookup TrueMoney, its something similar to PaySafeCard for us, but in thailand... gosh.

Comment: The PC cafés tend to be very odd setups so be sure to check into exactly which version of the legacy toolsets they require--often they don't allow games to run REDISTs or the latest DirectSetup. Keep in mind that Direct3D 9 debugging is not supported on Windows 8.x or Windows 10. Best of luck!